# How create users to work only with a specific domain/host on ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd

I'm new with ejabberd. I can create users by web admin, but all users work with all hosts. How do I limit a user to only one host?

Comment: Can you give more details with example? What is your configuration in .yml file?

Comment: For example, I have two virtual hosts working in the same database. When I create a user, this user don't have a specific virtualhost, it works with both virtualhosts.